IP addresses accessing my website bypassing Deny All in .htaccess
I am building my website. I added the following to my .htaccess to deny access to all IP addresses but mine.
#allow access only from my ip address
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <my IP address>

My shared hosting is Hostgator. Their cPanel has an option to check Visitors. When I check Visitors, the majority of access attempts show return codes 403, 406, or 409. I found two IP addresses trying to access "/" that got return code 200. One seems to be from Palo Alto in California. The other one is from China and shows as 100% chance of being malicious.
IP - 36.99.136.128 (this shows IP address from China with 100% chance of being malicious)
URL - /
Time - 7/25/24, 3:59 PM
Size (bytes) - 12097
Status - success 200
Method - GET
Protocol - HTTP/1.1
Referring URL - 
User Agent - Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 webmail.<my domain>.com <my server IP address>

IP - 205.210.31.75 (When I do a geolocation it shows this belongs to Palo Alto Networks, out of California)
URL - /
Time - 7/25/24, 11:31 PM
Size (bytes) - 37179
Status - success 200
Method - GET
Protocol - HTTP/1.1
Referring URL - 
User Agent - Expanse, a Palo Alto Networks company, searches across the global IPv4 space multiple times per day to identify customers&#39; presences on the Internet. If you would like to be excluded from our scans, please send IP addresses/domains to: scaninfo@paloaltonetworks.com cpanel.<my domain>.com <my server IP address>

Why are those two access attempts getting a 200 return code? Does it mean they bypassed the .htaccess block? Any suggestion on how to enforce the deny all for all IP addresses but mine?
Thank you.

The directives you are using are outdated and deprecated. They were last current for apache httpd version 2.2, that is many, many years ago. There are ways to still support those directives (order, deny, allow), namely the mod_access_compatible module, but that one has to be loaded into the apache server. You will have to check if that is the case. If not, and if you do not want to rely on totally outdated configuration options, you should replace them by the current directives offered by module mod_authz_host: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html

@arkascha Thank you. I checked the link you provided and searched for apache version 2.4 directives. I ended up with the following
Require all denied
Require ip 

@arkasha was spot on. I didn't realize the directives I was using was for apache 2.2.
I updated my directives to
Require all denied
Require ip <my IP address>

It has been approximately 12 hours since I made the change and it seems it is blocking all IPs. I will continue to monitor but I feel confident @arkasha had the right answer.
I hope this helps other people with the same issue. Thanks.

Thanks for posting this answer for others to find.
