HTACCESS RULE: limit access to the entire site to one IP BUT grant access to one directory for all IPs
I am trying to work out how to limit access to the site for all IPs, save one
but, at the same time, to allow full access to one dir and its subdirs.
Here's what I am after (more like a dummy example):
<Directory "/">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
allow from ***.***.*.*
</Directory>

and , additionally - the rule for a specific dir and its sub-directories:
<Directory "/dir-to-grant-access-to">
Order Deny,Allow
allow from all
</Directory>

ideally I need this in one block.
Thanks in advance!

Take a look at this question that has been asked just two days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78797581/ip-addresses-accessing-my-website-bypassing-deny-all-in-htaccess?noredirect=1#comment138932070_78797581

@arkascha  - Thanks but that question is not what I am looking for. I know how to disable access for all  IPs but grant to one. The second part of my question ("but, at the same time, to allow full access to one dir and its subdirs.") is what I am struggling with.

Easiest is to use an Alias directive for that AFAIK. Along with separate permissions.
